# expo project not working on expo start or npm start

Tags: node.js, reactjs, expo

Missing package "metro" in the project at /home/firefox/Projects/ReactNative/tween. This usually means `react-native` is not installed. Please verify that dependencies in package.json include "react-native" and run `yarn` or `npm install`.
Error: Missing package "metro" in the project at /home/firefox/Projects/ReactNative/tween. This usually means `react-native` is not installed. Please verify that dependencies in package.json include "react-native" and run `yarn` or `npm install`.
at importMetroFromProject (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/dev-server/src/MetroDevServer.ts:150:11)
at Object.runMetroDevServerAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/dev-server/src/MetroDevServer.ts:43:17)
at Object.startDevServerAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/src/start/startDevServerAsync.ts:56:55)
at startAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/xdl/src/start/startAsync.ts:92:41)

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of missing package(s), as is evident from the error log.
What all have you tried?

If it isn't resolved using

```
npm install
```

Include a snip of your package.json file.